# How to upgrade packages in VSCode/flutter?

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

I'm using VS Code on a flutter project. I just edited pubspec.yaml to point to a later version of a package, and it automatically ran 'flutter packages get'. In my '/development//flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org' directory, I can see both versions. But when I compile, it looks like it's still using the old version. I tried various things like 'flutter packages upgrade', 'flutter clean', etc., but to no avail. Looking at the 2 package versions' source code, I can see the change I want in the newer version. How do I point to the new package? Thanks.

Update:

It's the 'ethereum' package that's not updating. I had used the 3.0.0 version (method expects 2 args), and then switched to the 3.1.0 version (method expects 3 args). But compiling with a 3 arg call balks with incorrect argument count:

```
client.admin.personalSendTransaction(BigInt.parse(currentAddress), currentPassword,{});

[dart] Too many positional arguments: 2 expected, but 3 found. [extra_positional_arguments_could_be_named]
```

Yet hovering over the method call does show it expects 3 args:

```
personalSendTransaction(BigInt address, String passphrase, {BigInt to, BigInt data, int gas, int gasPrice, int value, int nonce, int condition, bool conditionIsTimestamp: false}) → Future<BigInt>
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
    dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  # Get package(s) for talking to ethereum node
  # web3dart: '>=0.3.0'
  ethereum: ^3.1.0

  # read barcodes and QR codes
  barcode_scan: ^0.0.3

  # Generate a QR code
  qr: ^1.0.1

  # Display as actual symbol
  qr_flutter: ^1.1.5

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

In pubspec.lock:

```
  ethereum:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: ethereum
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.1.0"
```

Version 3.1.0 is what I want to be used.

Running 'flutter packages upgrade resolved' yields:

```
[Gregorys-iMac]:(gkd) ~/Programs/wine_track $ flutter packages upgrade resolved
Running "flutter packages upgrade" in ....                   2.7s
```

In the package cache, I have both:

```
/Users/gkd/development//flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ethereum-3.0.0/lib/src/api/ethereum_api_admin.dart

/Users/gkd/development//flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ethereum-3.1.0/lib/src/api/ethereum_api_admin.dart
```

Comment: Could you add your pubspec file in your question? what package is not updating?

Comment: Check the `pubspec.lock` file what version `flutter packages upgrade resolved. What exactly does the dependency looks like that you added to `pubspec.yaml`?

Answer (score 57):

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

Answer (score 29):

you can simply run `flutter packages upgrade` in your project to upgrade all the packages. this feature is available from flutter version 1.17

Comment: it will both check and upgrade packages https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#updating-package-dependencies

Answer (score 7):

Just use

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

or

```
flutter packages upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

i have created a python3 script for this, you can use. this script only produce latest packages names and versions, you must to copy and paste into pubspec.yaml file.

```
import yaml
import requests
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO


def getNewVersion(pkg_name):
    url = f'https://pub.dev/packages/{pkg_name}'
    with requests.get(url) as req:
        doc = etree.parse(StringIO(req.text), etree.HTMLParser()).getroot()
        title = doc.xpath('//h2[@class="title"]')[0].text.strip()
        return '^' + (title.split(' ')[1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = 'pubspec.yaml'
    new_map = None
    with open(filename, 'r') as _f:
        docs = yaml.load(_f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
        deps = docs['dependencies']
        for package_name, old_version in deps.items():
            if package_name == 'flutter':
                continue
            last_version = getNewVersion(package_name)
            print(f'{package_name}: {last_version}')
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, never mind. This was my mistake. I interpreted the declaration's "{ type:variablename, . . .}" as a map/hash. In reality, they're Dart's optional named parameters. Just using any of them without the wrapping braces compiles clean.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **[pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages)** and find the latest package from there.

In there you can see an **install tab**. click that.

Now you can **add the dependencies** into your **pubspec.ymal** file in your Flutter project.

Then you can just press **ctrl+s in VS Code** or type **flutter pub get** in your terminal.

Now you can **import** into any page.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me with VS Code 1.87.2 and Flutter 3.19.4. Then I came across [this gem](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pflannery.vscode-versionlens).

I especially enjoy the fact that it color-codes the package lines in my pubspec.yaml file and has a spot to click and upgrade them right above the current version.

[image: Screenshot]