# I am working on a mobile app (6valley User App) but I keep getting this error "cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null."

Tags: flutter, dart

This a 6valley User App developed with Flutter but when I try to run it, I get the below error:

> /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-4.3.1/lib/src/flutter_typeahead.dart:800:29:
> Error: Method 'removeObserver' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?'
> because it is potentially null.
> 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart'). Try
> calling using ?. instead.
> WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-4.3.1/lib/src/flutter_typeahead.dart:824:29:
> Error: Method 'addObserver' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?'
> because it is potentially null.
> 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart'). Try
> calling using ?. instead.
> WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
> ^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-4.3.1/lib/src/flutter_typeahead.dart:881:29:
> Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on
> 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
> 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart'). Try
> calling using ?. instead.
> WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((duration) {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-4.3.1/lib/src/flutter_typeahead.dart:898:40:
> Error: Member not found: 'Scrollable.maybeOf'.
> final scrollableState = Scrollable.maybeOf(context);
> ^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-4.3.1/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:580:29:
> Error: Method 'removeObserver' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?'
> because it is potentially null.
> 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart'). Try
> calling using ?. instead.
> WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-4.3.1/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:593:29:
> Error: Method 'addObserver' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?'
> because it is potentially null.
> 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart'). Try
> calling using ?. instead.
> WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
> ^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-4.3.1/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:632:29:
> Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on
> 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
> 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart'). Try
> calling using ?. instead.
> WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((duration) {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-4.3.1/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:649:40:
> Error: Member not found: 'Scrollable.maybeOf'.
> final scrollableState = Scrollable.maybeOf(context);
> ^^^^^^^

I have tried using the latest version of flutter SDK but I had null safety compatibility issue. however, I downgraded my flutter SDK to 2.8.0 and the null safety issue is gone but I faced another challenge with the errors mentioned earlier.

Below is my `flutter doctor` report:

```bash
    [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.3007], locale en-US)
        • Flutter version 2.8.0 at C:\src\flutter
        • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
        • Framework revision cf44000065 (2 years, 2 months ago), 2021-12-08 14:06:50 -0800
        • Engine revision 40a99c5951
        • Dart version 2.15.0
    
    [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
        • Android SDK at C:\Users\Chinedu\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
        • Platform android-33, build-tools 34.0.0
        • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
        • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)
        • All Android licenses accepted.
    
    [√] Chrome - develop for the web
        • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    
    [√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
        • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
        • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
           https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
        • Dart plugin can be installed from:
           https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
        • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)
    
    [√] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
        • VS Code at C:\Users\Chinedu\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
        • Flutter extension version 3.80.0
    
    [√] Connected device (3 available)
        • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 14 (API 34) (emulator)
        • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 120.0.6099.225
        • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 120.0.2210.144
    
    • No issues found!
    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Below is my `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
    name: flutter_sixvalley_ecommerce
    description: A new Flutter setup application for starting a project.
    
    publish_to: 'none'
    
    version: 1.0.1+2
    
    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
    
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      flutter_localizations:
        sdk: flutter
    
      cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
      get_it: ^7.2.0
      provider: ^6.0.3
      connectivity: ^3.0.3
      dio: ^4.0.0-prev2
      http: ^0.13.1
      freezed: ^2.0.3+1
      shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
      fancy_bottom_navigation: ^0.3.3
      carousel_slider: ^4.0.0-nullsafety.0
      flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.1
      shimmer: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.0
      url_launcher: ^6.0.2
      image_picker: ^0.8.4+8
      webview_flutter: ^3.0.0
      flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.3
      share: ^2.0.1
      photo_view: ^0.14.0
      package_info: ^2.0.0
      firebase_core: ^1.7.0
      firebase_messaging: ^11.2.6
      flutter_local_notifications: ^9.0.0
      path_provider: ^2.0.1
      google_sign_in: ^5.1.0
      flutter_facebook_auth: ^4.0.1
      flutter_svg: ^1.0.3
      phone_number: ^0.12.0+1
      country_code_picker: ^2.0.2
      pin_code_fields: ^7.0.0
      google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.3
      flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
      geocoding: ^2.0.0
      geolocator: ^8.2.0
      flutter_typeahead: ^4.0.0
      marquee: ^2.2.1
      flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0
      flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.8.5
      flutter_widget_from_html_core: ^0.8.5+3
      flutter_html_table: ^3.0.0-alpha.3
      fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
    
    dependency_overrides:
      firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 3.1.6
    
    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
    
    flutter:
      uses-material-design: true
    
      assets:
        - assets/images/
        - assets/language/
    
      fonts:
        - family: Ubuntu
          fonts:
            - asset: assets/fonts/ubuntu/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf
              weight: 400
            - asset: assets/fonts/ubuntu/Ubuntu-Medium.ttf
              weight: 500
            - asset: assets/fonts/ubuntu/Ubuntu-Bold.ttf
              weight: 600
```

Comment: i think the problem is flutter_typeahead package. See the `flutter_typeahead-4.3.1` part, when i see to the pub page https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead the latest version is 5.0.2 and yours is 4.3.1. Try to update your packages, there's many option to upgrade your package, please check this discussion to see what method that fit you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53731646/how-to-upgrade-packages-in-vscode-flutter